# Data not echoing inside div

Tags: php, html, css

I am echoing data from my database and trying to show it inside of a div that is inside of another div. But it isn't showing inside the correct div.[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVmHh.png)

I am trying to put `You said:   Hello  2hrs` next to the name and profile pic. I can't find a problem with it. There are no errors. Can someone please help me ?

messages.php:

```
<div class="user_convos convos_column" id="convos">
    
    <h4>Conversations</h4>
    <br>

    <div class='loaded_conversations' style='position: absolute;'></div>


    <?php echo $message_obj->getConvos(); ?>
    
<a href="messages.php?u=new">New Message</a>

<br><br>

</div>
```

styles.css:

```
.user_found_messages {

padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
height: auto;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.user_found_messages:hover {

background-color: #F2F2F2;
color: #669999;
}

.user_found_messages img {

height: 105px;
float: left;
margin-top: 1px; 
margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

Message.php(class)

```
public function getLatestMessage ($userLoggedIn, $user2) {

    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT body, user_to, date FROM messages WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND user_from = ? OR user_to = ? AND user_from = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

    $query->bind_param("ssss", $userLoggedIn, $user2, $user2, $userLoggedIn);
    $query->execute();
    //$query->bind_result($body, $user_to, $date);
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

     while ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Timeframe
        $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $start_date = new DateTime($row['date']); //Time of post
        $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates 
        if($interval->y >= 1) {
            if($interval->y == 1)
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yr"; //1 year ago
            else 
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yrs"; //1+ year ago
        }
        else if ($interval-> m >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 0) {
                $days = " ago";
            }
            else if($interval->d == 1) {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }
            else {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }

            if($interval->m == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "month";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "months";
            }

        }
        else if($interval->d >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 1) {
                $time_message = "Yesterday";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->d . "d ";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->h >= 1) {
            if($interval->h == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hr";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hrs";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->i >= 1) {
            if($interval->i == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
        }
        else {
            if($interval->s < 30) {
                $time_message = "Just now";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->s . " seconds ago";
            }
        }

        echo $sent_by = ($row['user_to'] == $userLoggedIn) ? "They said: " : "You said: ";
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo $body = $row['body'];
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo $time_message ;
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo "<br>";
    }   
        
    //return $query;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
public function getConvos () {

    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $return_string = "";
    $convos = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT user_to, user_from FROM messages WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn' OR 
        user_from='$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $user_to_push = ($row['user_to'] != $userLoggedIn) ? $row['user_to'] : $row['user_from'];

        if(!in_array($user_to_push, $convos)) {

            array_push($convos, $user_to_push);

        }
    }

    foreach ($convos as $username) {

        $user_found_obj = new User($this->con, $username);
        $latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);

        $dots = (strlen($latest_message_details[1]) >= 12) ? "..." : "";
        $split = str_split($latest_message_details[1], 12);
        $split = $split[0] . $dots;

        $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'><div class='user_found_messages'>
                        <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . 
                        "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
                        ". $user_found_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . "
                        <span class='timestamp_smaller' id='grey'> " . $latest_message_details[2] . "</span>
                        <p id='grey' style='margin-right: 10px;'> " . $latest_message_details[0] . $split . " </p>
                        </div></a>";
    }

    return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? The code sent to the browser without the PHP

Comment: I honestly don't know where to find that

Comment: @DonJohn you'd use the "View Source" feature of your browser to see that. Or the element inspector in the browser's Developer Tools. But anyway, although your info isn't 100% clear I've made a stab at what I think you want - see the answer below.

Comment: As a side, I noticed you have `id='grey'` in many many places (and inside a foreach loop). Keep in mind that ALL `id` in an html output must be unique. Only one applies in regards to everything dealing with an element of `id`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the line

`echo "<br>";`

from the `getLatestMessage` function - this adds a new line which you don't want.

Secondly turn all the echo's in that function into string concatenation and then return the string from the function - this gives you more control over where you use the results it generates.

Third, try to echo the message data inside the `user_found_messages` div - because divs are block-level elements which also generally start a new line (unless a CSS rule tells them not to).

So, something like this I think:

```
public function getLatestMessage ($userLoggedIn, $user2) {

    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT body, user_to, date FROM messages WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND user_from = ? OR user_to = ? AND user_from = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

    $query->bind_param("ssss", $userLoggedIn, $user2, $user2, $userLoggedIn);
    $query->execute();
    //$query->bind_result($body, $user_to, $date);
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    $msg = ""; //to hold the message data

     if ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) { //don't need a while here because we've limited the query to one record

        //Timeframe
        $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $start_date = new DateTime($row['date']); //Time of post
        $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates 
        if($interval->y >= 1) {
            if($interval->y == 1)
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yr"; //1 year ago
            else 
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yrs"; //1+ year ago
        }
        else if ($interval-> m >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 0) {
                $days = " ago";
            }
            else if($interval->d == 1) {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }
            else {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }

            if($interval->m == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "month";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "months";
            }

        }
        else if($interval->d >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 1) {
                $time_message = "Yesterday";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->d . "d ";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->h >= 1) {
            if($interval->h == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hr";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hrs";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->i >= 1) {
            if($interval->i == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
        }
        else {
            if($interval->s < 30) {
                $time_message = "Just now";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->s . " seconds ago";
            }
        }

        $msg .= ($row['user_to'] == $userLoggedIn) ? "They said: " : "You said: ";
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $msg .= $body = $row['body'];
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $msg .= $time_message ;
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }   
        
    return $msg;
}

public function getConvos () {

    $userLoggedIn = $this->user_obj->getUsername();
    $return_string = "";
    $convos = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT user_to, user_from FROM messages WHERE user_to='$userLoggedIn' OR 
        user_from='$userLoggedIn' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $user_to_push = ($row['user_to'] != $userLoggedIn) ? $row['user_to'] : $row['user_from'];

        if(!in_array($user_to_push, $convos)) {
            array_push($convos, $user_to_push);
        }
    }

    foreach ($convos as $username) {
        $user_found_obj = new User($this->con, $username);
        $latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);

        $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'><div class='user_found_messages'>
                        <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . 
                        "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
                        ". $user_found_obj->getFirstAndLastName() ."<br/>".
                         $latest_message_details . "</div></a>";
    }

    return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: Ok I just looked a bit closer and maybe understood a bit better now. I think you need to remove the `echo "<br>";` from this bit here: `echo $sent_by = ($row['user_to'] == $userLoggedIn) ? "They said: " : "You said: ";
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo $body = $row['body'];
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo $time_message ;
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo "<br>";`. Because `<br>` creates a new line in the HTML document.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I was doing this using an unsecured method and it was perfectly fine.

Comment: `<div class='loaded_conversations'>


  You said: &nbsp;&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;3hrs&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><a href='messages.php?u=brandon_tisson'><div class='user_found_messages'>
       <img src='assets/images/profile_pics/b19d0ac51499996d9b4dc1882c3ee3b8n.jpeg' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
       Doe John
       <span class='timestamp_smaller' id='grey'> </span>
       <p id='grey' style='margin-right: 10px;'>  </p>
       </div></a>  </div>`

Comment: I see the `<br>` is still there in that. So please double-check you removed it.

Comment: Sorry about that I pulled it up before I removed the br

Comment: `<div class='loaded_conversations'>


  You said: &nbsp;&nbsp;Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;3hrs&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='messages.php?u=brandon_tisson'><div class='user_found_messages'>
       <img src='assets/images/profile_pics/b19d0ac51499996d9b4dc1882c3ee3b8n.jpeg' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
       Doe John
       <span class='timestamp_smaller' id='grey'> </span>
       <p id='grey' style='margin-right: 10px;'>  </p>
       </div></a>  
  </div>`

Comment: ok so next thing is that a `<div>` is usually a block-level element, which will start a new line as well. And i see nothing in the definition of the user_found_messages which would alter that. So maybe you need to move the call to `$this->getLatestMessage` so that it will echo inside that div

Comment: what exactly did you change?

Comment: I moved this `$latest_message_details = $this->getLatestMessage($userLoggedIn, $username);` into the `$return_string`

Comment: If I post how I was doing it before would that help you get a better understanding ?

Comment: You mean you had it working before? Why did you change it then? Anyway I totally re-wrote the answer with what I hope will be more helpful. Take a look

Comment: I had to change it because it wasn't using prepared statements. Ok I'll take a look

Comment: "I had to change it because it wasn't using prepared statements"...that wouldn't / shouldn't have affected how you did the output though! Those should be entirely separate concerns. But anyway glad it's working better for you now.